# JavaScript class removing doesn't apply transition

Tags: javascript, css, dom, getelementsbyclassname, htmlcollection

Hey I have this problem that when I'm removing class dynamically it doesn't apply transition. Don't worry problem isn't with class itself, because when I try to delete manually trough dev tools it applies transition.

Here is the situation. I have big popup but lets just write it like this.

```
<div class="popup hidden">
  <div class="popup__content hidden">
    Bunch of stuff here that doesn't really matter
  </div>
</div>
```

I am generating this markup into its container with insertAdjacentHTML. I have removeHidden method that looks like this

```
removeHidden(arr) {
     [...arr].forEach(el => el.classList.remove('hidden'));
  }
```

And I'm calling this method with passing a html collection as an argument, in this case those are both of the divs that have a hidden class.

```
removeHidden(document.getElementsByClassName('hidden'));
```

Now everything works fine, I mean classes are removed, my popup is shown, except that I don't get that nice transition I built into these classes, which works fine when deleting automatically which I already said just to note You that that is not a problem.

Thanking you all in advance for solving this problem! ;)

Comment: Can you share your CSS? You should put transition property to the non hidden element, in your case `.popup`. If you have transition only on `.hidden` class, than, it is only works when hides it.

Comment: Yes transition is on .popup class, transition: all 0.5s. I already wrote down that's not the problem. I just tried to put my popup inside its container manually, did the same and transition worked. Problem occurs when I'm adding it dynamically trough insertAdjacentHtml.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just added timer where after 0.2 seconds those classes are removed.